# Adobe AIR - Captive runtime

Tags: apache-flex, air, runtime

I'm using Adobe Flash CS5 with Adobe Air 2.5 to build an air app.

Is there a way to make use of the Air 3 captive runtime feature? Do I need additional software to publish the Air app with the captive runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Captive Runtime is not yet integrated into the Flash Pro IDE.  You'll have to package your app using the command line tools available in the free [AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/sdk/).

Some more info [is here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html); basically when you compile your app be sure to specify the target parameter.  To create an Android APK, you would use this:

```
-target apk-captive-runtime
```

More info on options is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a generator available for the command line tags?